# Disable analysis for Elasticsearch multi_match query

Tags: elasticsearch

My index uses the following mapping:

```
"mappings": {
  "user": {
    "properties": {
      "address": {
        "properties": {
          "number": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "street": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using the following query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "mystreet 5",
            "fields": "address.*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This returns all objects where `address.street` equals `mystreet` OR `address.number` equals `5` because the multi_match query is analyzed.

However, I'd rather search for the exact string. So I would like to disable the analyzer for the query. Basically I need a `term` query that queries multiple fields `address.*`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to achieve this just by specifying `phrase` type in your `multi_match` query like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "mystreet 5",
            "fields": "address.*",
            "type": "phrase"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This will match `lincoln mystreet 5` but wont give you `lincoln mystreet` or `some street 5`.

If you are looking for exact full field match like *mystreet 5* should not match *JFK mystreet 5*, then you can use `multi-fields` and analyze each of your field twice, one with `standard analyzer` and other with `keyword analyzer`.

Hope this helps!